# Почему когда мы реализуем UserDetailsService, в методе loadUserByUsername мы в аргументах получаем username?

Tags: java, spring

Я начал изучать Spring Security, и столкнулся с непониманием, почему когда мы реализуем `UserDetailsService`, в методе `loadUserByUsername`, в аргументах получаем только `username`. А что делать, если у меня два юзера с одинаковыми юзернеймами? Или юзернейм должен быть уникален? Если так зачем, тогда использовать id?

Comment: Username - это просто какое-то уникальное строковое поле, не обязательно username. Это может быть email, например

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из документации `UserDetailsService`

```
* @param username the username identifying the user whose data is required.
```

Это то значение которое пользователь вводит в поле логин при входе на сайт и дальше с помощью этого идентификатора пользователя проверяется пароль (достается с БД запись пользователя для сравнения пароля БД с входным)